# Reload listview.builder inside a widget from parent page

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, widget, stateful

I started developing on flutter 5 months ago for my school project and I have a problem.

I made a custom `Widget` that uses `Listview.builder()` lets call this **myList** widget, it is called in **parentPage**, then, I add a new item to my database from **myList** then `setState()` to the **parentPage** where I am loading my items from database, **parentPage** is reloading however **myList** and its items are not. **parentPage**  & **myList** are both stateful.

My question is how can you build (or init?) a second time **myList** so that the item added is shown.

I saw similar questions but I couldn't understand how I could apply the answers to `listview.builder()`

I'm sorry, I cannot put any code I am not allowed because of a contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call child widget's method from parent widget, which is possible using global key.

I just demonstrated how to do it in following code.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  callme() {
    print("here, you have to load data, method in delete from home1");
    setState((){}); // added
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Home1(
          callme: callme,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callme;
  Home1({this.callme});
  @override
  _Home1State createState() => _Home1State();
}

class _Home1State extends State<Home1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("press"),
        onPressed: () {
          print("here you add data in database");
          widget.callme();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood me my bad, if i take your exemple the raised button would be in home1state build, when pressing it, it would add an item to my database and then reload _DeleteWidgetState where in his init method i load items from my database which would then feed home1's items (for listview.builder() ) but since home1 is already built, data is not reloading

Comment: calling init state is not possible, so you have to create a separate method, which you can call and load data.

Comment: the update is basically what i currently have and with this, data is not reloading

Comment: you have to call setState in call me method. i edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  List<String> items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    getDataFromDataBase();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: MyList(
          items: items,
          refreshData: initState,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getDataFromDataBase() {
//    Get Data from Database
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        items.add("Name $i");
      }
    });
  }
}

class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function refreshData;
  List<String> items = [];

  MyList({this.refreshData, this.items});

  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(widget.items[index]),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Add item in Database"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    addItem();
                    widget.refreshData();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: widget.items.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  addItem() {
//    Add item in database
  }
}
```